# SonarQube Scanner is borking on javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube Scanner is borking on javascript/typescript

```
10:33:14.808 ERROR: Unable to parse file: C:/Users/marc.donovan/wk/pos-web-framework/packages/pos-web-error-manager/src/index.js
10:33:14.811 ERROR: Parse error at line 4 column 13:

4: export type {
                ^
5:   ErrorReport, 
6: };
```

And also here:

```
450:   getTerminalAvailableKeyboardMappings$(props: { terminalId: String }): Rx.Observable<[] | void> {
```

Answer (score 1):

Flow syntax support (what is probably your case, and not typescript as you said) is provided since SonarJS 3.2. See [this issue](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/584).

Probably you just need to update your plugin version.

Comment: I'm using 3.2.0.5506 jar. I think I need to wait for this https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/771 to be addressed. Although I don't see the export syntax on there and it looks like it was removed from the next milestone.